# beyond compare force `compare folder` use `text compare`

Tags: windows, beyondcompare

Both beyond compare 3 & 4 use `binary compare` when `compare folder`.
Many files are actully have same content but show as diff(red color),  I know it due to  [line ends difference between linux and windows](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_samebutdifferent), but I don't find a way to change that in `options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Folder Compare settings compare file size and modified timestamp.

To compare the text contents of files in the Folder Compare and ignore line ending differences (Windows CRLF vs Unix/Linux LF), click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon). In the **Comparison** tab, check **Compare Contents**. Select **Rules-based comparison**.

To make Rules-based comparison the default setting for new Folder Compare sessions, change the dropdown in the dialog from **Use for this view only** to **Also update session defaults** before you click OK.